# Где хранить токены Android?

Tags: android, token

Есть веб сервер , который после успешной аутентификации отдает 2 токена (доступа и обновления) . Где их безопасно хранить? Shared Preferences с private mode не кажется мне лучшей идеей.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый лучший вариант - использовать системный менеджер аккаунтов, который предоставляет возможность безопасно хранить данные пользователя и даже использовать их в нескольких приложениях одновременно. Есть замечательные статьи на эту тему:

Часть 1 - https://habrahabr.ru/company/e-Legion/blog/206210/

Часть 2 - https://habrahabr.ru/company/e-Legion/blog/216857/

А также документация - https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html

Comment: Огромный плюс, совсем забыл про них!

Comment: Вообще, достать информацию и менеджера аккаунтов не сложнее, чем из Shared Preferences с private mode. Вся инфа хранится в одной базе данных, которая, по крайней мере во времена 4го андроида, никаким дополнительным образом не шифровалась. Если у пользователя есть root-права, чтобы залезть в приватный сторадж приложения, он точно так же может скачать и базу со всем токенами  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632237/where-does-android-account-manager-store-account-specific-preferences

Comment: @Agrgg а есть какие-то мысли что можно наколдовать , зашифровать не выйдет:исходник скачают и увидят алгоритм шифрования