# Intent vs shared preferences

Tags: android, kotlin

Что быстрее|эффективнее|безопаснее: брать в первой активити из шаред преференсес всякие настройки (токен от базы там, тему и прочее), или обращатся к шаред преференсес из каждой активити?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос максимально непонятный и имеет довольно странную формулировку. Могу предположить что при адекватной формулировке он бы выглядел так:

> Как  быстрее|эффективнее|безопаснее передавать полученные в первой
> активности токены: через intent (как строку) или сохранить в
> SharedPreferences и вытаскивать в каждой активности где необходимо.

Теперь пройдемся по упомянутым вами пунктам:

1. **Скорость** - на мой взгляд человеку без супер способностей будет сложно заметить задержку при несколько миллисекунд при вытаскивании данных из памяти устройства посредством SharedPreferences. Поэтому по скорости работы приложения эти методы одинаковы на мой взгляд.
2. **Эффективность** - основываясь на своем опыте могу сказать что эффективнее сохранить токен в память и вытаскивать где нужно. При использовании intent у вас будет ряд сложностей в процессе разработки: нужно не натупить и передать/получить токен из активности A/B. Так же стоит учитывать тот факт что если неожиданно вам понадобится токен где-то за пределами активностей, то вы его никак не сможете использовать, только опять таки передавать через какие-то костыли. При использовании SharedPreferences вы один раз сохраняете и вытаскиваете везде где вам нужно при наличии контекста в классе/методе.
3. **Безопасность** - это довольно популярный вопрос при работе с токенами доступа. Сам по себе токен это уже зашифрованные данные которые вам передает сервер. Чтобы более подробно ознакомится с тем что вы получили от сервера советую воспользоваться [этим инструментом](https://jwt.io/). Если ваше приложение все-таки кто-то захочет взломать и вытащить данные то вас не спасет ни intent, ни SP ни дверь в квартире где вы живете :) По заявлениям от Google использовать SharedPreferences для хранения такого рода информации вполне безопасно и надежно.

Я использую в своем приложении SharedPreferences для хранения ключей доступа и другой информации. Это удобно и дает возможность взять токен везде где есть средства. Так же вот есть несколько вопросов связанных с вашей проблемой: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685491/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-android), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/884081/%D0%9B%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8). Вот [тут описан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1098856/%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-sharedpreferences) механизм сохранения токена. [Туториал](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php) по работе с SP.